# AppStore issue with B2B app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store, b2b

I try to upload the application as B2B app

I found some advices at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843575/how-are-b2b-ios-apps-approved) and at [apple web site](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) (Select the custom B2B distribution option in iTunes Connect. If your app contains sensitive data, you should provide sample data and authentication for our review team.)

The problem is I don't know how to "Select the custom B2B distribution option in iTunes Connect".

I've uploaded the application to itunes connect (see attached image, I draw client's private data)

[image]

I don't know where to select "this is a B2B app"

**Update:**

Rights and Pricing section

[image]

Contracts, Tax, and Banking

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH34-SW1). You need to configure `Volume Purchase Program` options and then look in the `Rights and Pricing` section.

Comment: right now my application status is Waiting for Upload. Do I need to upload build to app store before confguring Volume Purchase Program? (because right now I don't see custom B2B app in Rights and Pricing section. I will upload screen for Rights and Pricing section in a minute

Comment: `Volume Purchase Program` should come first.

Comment: ok, right now I uploaded screenshot of Rights and Pricing section, pls take a look

Comment: Are all of your paid app and tax contracts approved with Apple?

Comment: I updated question with Contracts, Tax, and Banking section. I don't have payed applications. And the application I need to upload for B2B is free and it's the first application in this itunes account.

Comment: you can see in Tax information that only information for iOS Free Applications was requested and approved. Do my client need to request iOS Paid Applications and iAd Network contract types too?

Comment: I believe you need a paid app agreement even to release free B2B apps... I don't think iAd is required.